# Telerik : preventing postback with RadButton confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am having trouble to implement the confirm dialog to ask the user to confirm his choice to delete. The RadButton should not postback to the server if the user clicks cancel. The confirm dialog never shows, what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmAspButton(button) {
        function aspButtonCallbackFn(arg) {
            if (arg) {
                __doPostBack(button.name, "");
            }
        }
        radconfirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", aspButtonCallbackFn, 330, 110, null, "Confirm");
    }
</script>


<telerik:RadButton
    ID="btnDeleteLines" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClientClicking="confirmAspButton(this); return false;"
    OnClick="btnDeleteLines_Click"
    Text="Delete line(s)"
    AutoPostBack="false"
    GroupName="GroupName1">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found out a way described on [the telerik website](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/confirm/defaultcs.aspx), the `CustomRadWindowConfirm`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Custom RadWindow Confirm
    function CustomRadWindowConfirm(sender, args)
    {
        //Open the window
        $find("<%= confirmWindow.ClientID %>").show();
        //Focus the Yes button
        $find("<%= btnYes.ClientID %>").focus();
        //Cancel the postback
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
    function YesOrNoClicked(sender, args)
    {
        var oWnd = $find("<%= confirmWindow.ClientID %>");
        oWnd.close();
        if (sender.get_text() == "Yes")
        {
            $find("<%= btnDeleteLines.ClientID %>").click();
        }
    }
</script>


<telerik:RadButton
    ID="btnDeleteLines" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClientClicking="CustomRadWindowConfirm"
    OnClick="btnDeleteLines_Click"
    Text="Delete line(s)"
    AutoPostBack="false"
    GroupName="GroupName1">
</telerik:RadButton>
```